# Secure way to access Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have been using Transmit FTP program to access my Amazon S3 storage buckets. Just been reading on here that this isn't that secure.

I'm not a command line person as you can probably tell so what would be the best way for me to access my S3 storage on my Mac?

I'm using to store image files that I am making available for download on my website.

Thanks

Comment: Many clients support the native S3 API. I use Cyberduck.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand this, I personally use Transmit. I was really looking for an alternative to FTP as I've read its not that secure.

Comment: Yes, the native S3 API is a secure alternative to FTP.

Answer (score 0):

FTP isn't secure, but it sounds like you are confusing this fact with the fact that you are using a multiprotocol client to access S3, and that client also happens to support FTP.

S3 *cannot* be directly accessed using the FTP protocol, so the client you are using can't actually be accessing S3 using FTP... hence, your security-related concern appears to be unfounded.